# Set env variable for NPM build step

Tags: npm, azure-devops

Using terminal on my dev machine, I can do this...

```
SOME_VARIABLE=http://localhost:3000/ npm start
```

... and SOME_VARIABLE is accessible in the code using...

```
process.env.SOME_VARIABLE
```

Using the NPM build [step](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/package/npm?view=vsts) in Azure DevOps, how do I set the same environment variable?

I can't add the variable in the "Command and arguments" text field because they're added *after* the generated call to npm.

Furthermore, if I copy the command that works on my dev machine and run it from a command line task, it won't accept the command format, I presume because it's Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the existing answer is not what you would want, probably. what you want to do is go to build setting > variables and declare it there

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/options?view=vsts&tabs=yaml#variables

Comment: Build variables are picked up as environment variables?!